# Why using Google Cloud Drive Rest API file.list can not get all the files?

Tags: rest, sdk, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, drive

I am using the following CURL command to retrieve all my google drive files, however, it only list a very limited part of the whole bunch of files. Why?

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.hereshouldbethemaskedaccesstokenvalue" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

result

```
{
"kind": "drive#fileList",
"incompleteSearch": false,
"files": [
{
"kind": "drive#file",
id": "2fileidxxxxxxxx",
"name": "testnum",
"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
},
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "1fileidxxxxxxx",
"name": "test2.txt",
...
}
```

token scope includes
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata

Using the Android SDK also facing the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Results from files.list are paginated -- your response should include a "nextPageToken" field, and you'll have to make another call for the next page of results. See documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) about the files list call. You may want to use one of the client libraries to make this call (see the examples at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Thanks Alex,
I only got 7 files/folders in total, by default the page size is 10.

I also tried to list file under one specific folder in another test. That folder has two subfolders and 5 text files. I can only get 2 text files in the response. This seems not due to the Pagination. 

I tried with Android client SDK first and got this issue, thus I tried REST API again to simplify it for testing, but got the same error behavior.

Comment: the pagesize specifies the **maximum**, not the **absolute** number of files in a response. You need to check for a nextpagetoken as per the documentation,

Comment: Thanks pinoyyid. I understand when setting the pagesize to 10, the return number of files would be **less** or **equal** to 10. In my case, the returned file number is 7 even when the pagesize is set to 10. 
I think the 'nextPageToken' will not be in the response when the results are fully returned within the first response as the one I paste in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when try to get list of files in Google Drive folder. This folder has more than 5000 files, but API return only two of them. The problem is -- when files in folder shared with anyone with a link, in fact it isn't shared with you until you open it. Owner of this folder must specify you as viewer.

Comment: The issue folder is owned under the same account of the REST API google user.